# Entry widget won't display

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to write an app that computes a figure after compound interest over time, but one of my entry boxes isn't showing up. The get function appears to work but the second entry box won't display:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("600x200")

    #frm = ttk.Frame(root, padding=100)
    e1 = ttk.Entry(root, width=20, rowspan=1)
    e2 = ttk.Entry(root, width=20, rowspan=1)
    e3 = ttk.Entry(root, width=20, rowspan=1)

    e11 = e1.get()
    e22 = e2.get()
    e33 = e3.get()
    e1.grid(column=1, row=0)
    e2.grid(column=1, row=1)
    e2.grid(column=1, row=2)

    Label(root, text="Amount to invest:").grid(column=0, row=0)
    Label(root, text="Number of years invested:").grid(column=0, row=1)
    Label(root, text="Add yearly return in percent:").grid(column=0, row=2)

    submit = Button(root, text="Submit", command=lambda: Label(root, int(e11)*(int(e22)**int(e33))), padx=10, bg="cyan", fg="Red")
    submit.grid(column=1, row=3)

    enter code here
    root.mainloop()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You are calling `e2.grid()` twice, and `e3.grid()` not at all.  Also, I'm a bit worried by the lines like `e11 = e1.get()` - the Entry was just created a millisecond ago, the result of `.get()` can only be an empty string at this point in time.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, but I removed the rowspan parameter

```
e1 = ttk.Entry(root, width=20, )
e2 = ttk.Entry(root, width=20, )
e3 = ttk.Entry(root, width=20, )
e11 = e1.get()
e22 = e2.get()
e33 = e3.get()
e1.grid(column=1, row=0)
e2.grid(column=1, row=1)
e3.grid(column=1, row=2)
```

[image]